# Отступ vuetify v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Не получается убрать отступ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда он берётся? Мне нужно, чтобы селектор был вертикально выровнен по центру. Вот полное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рабочий код по [ссылке](https://codepen.io/asdakkcxclal/pen/NWxGmOr)

Разметка:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">

      <div class="selectors-menu-section debug">
          <v-select
              :items="[]"
              label="Редактируемые"
              dense
              outlined
          ></v-select>
      </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Стили:

```
  .debug {
    border: 2px black solid;
  }

  .selectors-menu-section {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      padding-left: 20px;
      width: 200px;
  }
```

Скрипты:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к `v-select` атрибут `hide-details`, он так же применим к различным инпутам и выпадающим спискам которые есть внутри vuetify.

Так же бывают ситуации в которых помогают `spacing-helpers`: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">

      <div class="selectors-menu-section debug">
          <v-select
              hide-details
              :items="[]"
              label="Редактируемые"
              dense
              outlined
          ></v-select>
      </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: За что отвечает `hide-details`? Почему он занимает доп. место? `Hides hint and validation errors. When set to auto messages will be rendered only if there's a message (hint, error message, counter value etc) to display`. Эта фраза не ясно, про какие ошибки говорит. А самое главное, не ясно, почему это занимает доп место.

Comment: @hedgehogues Это зарезервированное место для всяких счетчиков и сообщений валидации, можно поставть его так же в режим auto, если вы собираетесь эти сообщения выводить

Comment: Огонь, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Правая кнопка мыши -> Просмотреть код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ага, это тоже уже подсказали. Спасибо. Я всегда об этом забываю и смотрю как баран на новые ворота на картинку браузера.